# Underlying logical structure behind Descartes' Ontological argument?

Tags: logic, theology, proof, descartes

Quoting [SEP](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-ontological/#1):

> ```
> Version A:
> ```
>
> 1. Whatever I clearly and distinctly perceive to be contained in the
>      idea of something is true of that thing.
> 2. I clearly and distinctly perceive that necessary existence is contained in the idea of God.
> 3. Therefore, God exists.
>
> Version B:
>
> 1. I have an idea of supremely perfect being, i.e. a being having all
>      perfections.
> 2. Necessary existence is a perfection.
> 3. Therefore, a supremely perfect being exists.

How can I convert it to first-order logic? Furthermore, how can we test for the validity of the rule of inference?

**Edit: How sound is the argument?**

Comment: Criticism of Descartes' argument from Alexander Pruss [here](http://alexanderpruss.blogspot.com/2021/05/cartesian-style-ontological-arguments.html) (Pruss is a Catholic philosopher who does advocate a different form of the ontological argument, discussed in [his book](https://www.amazon.com/Necessary-Existence-Alexander-R-Pruss-ebook/dp/B07B53FCP2))

Comment: I recommend reading https://figshare.com/articles/book/The_Aperio_24th_Edition/20705311 in the section “God, Platonism, and Creation” and “Implications of S7”.

Answer (score 3):

They are both simple variations on *[Modus Ponens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens)*, and I don't think that anybody questions that the inferences are *valid*; what is at stake is whether or not they are *sound*.

**EDIT:**

The general consensus is that the arguments are not sound; there is no particular reason to believe that "necessary existence is a perfection", or that "perfections" are even an appropriate concept here: does it make sense to conceive of a perfectly large (i.e., largest) integer?

Comment: I edited the question appropriately.